# Deleting one character - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout

How do I delete one character of output in Python3?

For instance, I just ran

```py
print("Hello, World!")
```

But I want my STDOUT to say:

```
Hello, World
```

.

I will not accept answers that prints many newlines, but I will accept answers that clear the screen instead.

I am OK with modules, but I don't particularly flavor them.

Comment: Which character you want to delete? The last? The exclamation mark? You can achieve this by setting a variable and then performing some manipulation with str.replace, re.sub, or similiar methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the output that you want printed to a variable and then just display all except the last character:

```
to_print = "Hello, World!"
print(to_print[:-1])
```

If you want to delete the last char you can also re-assign to the variable using the same method:

```
to_print = "Hello, World!"
to_print = to_print[:-1]
print(to_print)
```